# Practical Git example (git status does not show untracked/changed file)

Tags: git, git-status

I'm currently reviewing *Practical Git* by Johan Abildskov in preparation for an upcoming job. The first example I came across seems to be impossible.

Here's how it starts:

```
$ ls
A B C D
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ echo testing > A
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

How did he get to this situation? If A is untracked, wouldn't git alert him about the untracked file? If A IS tracked, wouldn't git alert him that the file had changed?

I've been wracking my brain, but I can't figure out how your repository would get to this state.

Comment: Maybe he has `A` listed in the `.gitignore`?

Comment: What was the content of `A` before the change? If it already contained the single word "testing" `git` would not detect a change.  `git` does not care for *change date* it only looks at the content of files.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a few ways this can happen.

First, you could have the configuration option `status.showUntrackedFiles` set to `no` (either locally for this repo, or globally).

Second, you could have a `.gitignore` entry configured to ignore `A`.

Third, as Timothy Truckle mentioned in the comments, `echo testing > A` overwrites the contents of `A` with the string `testing`. If that was its content before the `echo` command, from git's perspective there'd be no change (i.e., nothing to report about in `git status`), since the content of the file is unchanged.

Comment: Odd that he doesn't mention either of those things. Maybe it's an error in the book.

Comment: @NaNCat: Maybe - or perhaps he's illustrating some other weird corner case, such as what happens when you use sparse checkout or some of the special flags with `git update-index` (one of which is meant for sparse checkout). Hard to say without looking at the book, which I don't have. :-)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe, your A file is in the .gitignore file.

Comment: git is definitely already initialized or it would not have printed that it was on branch master